# Fastest String Filtering Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-science, mathematical-optimization, data-scrubbing

I have 5,000,000 unordered strings formatted this way (Name.Name.Day-Month-Year 24hrTime):

```
"John.Howard.12-11-2020 13:14"
"Diane.Barry.29-07-2020 20:50"
"Joseph.Ferns.08-05-2020 08:02"
"Joseph.Ferns.02-03-2020 05:09"
"Josephine.Fernie.01-01-2020 07:20"
"Alex.Alexander.06-06-2020 10:10"
"Howard.Jennings.07-07-2020 13:17"
"Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 00:49"
...
```

What is the fastest way to find all strings having a time t between some n and m? (i.e. fastest way to remove all strings whose time < n || m < time)

This filtering will be done multiple times with different ranges. Time ranges must always be on the same day and the starting time is always earlier than the end time.

In java, heres's my current approach given some time string M and N and a 5 million string list:

```
ArrayList<String> finalSolution = new ArrayList<>();

String[] startingMtimeArr = m.split(":");
String[] startingNtimeArr = n.split(":");
Integer startingMhour = Integer.parseInt(startingMtimeArr[0]);
Integer startingMminute = Integer.parseInt(startingMtimeArr[1]);
Integer endingNhour = Integer.parseInt(startingNtimeArr[0]);
Integer endingNminute = Integer.parseInt(startingNtimeArr[1]);

for combinedString in ArraySizeOf5Million{
  String[] arr = combinedString.split(".");
  String[] subArr = arr[2].split(" ");
  String[] timeArr = subArr[1].split(":");
  String hour = timeArr[0];
  String minute = timeArr[1];

   If hour >= startingMhour 
        && minute >= startingMminute 
        && hour <= endingNhour 
        && minute <= endingNminute {
    finalSolution.add(hour)
   } 
}
```

Java's my native language but any other languages work too. Better/faster logic is what I am after

Comment: As often, the answer is "it depends". Do you have to do that filtering only once for a given time or do you need to the filtering again and again, with different parameters. For the question as asked I wonder what time improvements you are hoping for and especially what method you already have employed.

Comment: Well, you've got to read and parse every line ,no matter what you do, so you might as well test each line for 'in range' after you read it.  500 strings doesn't seem very many.

Comment: @Yunnosch filtering will happen again and again with different m and n values. The amount of strings remains a constant 5,000,000

Comment: @iggy missed a few zeros

Comment: That makes all the difference!

Comment: You can sort the strings by time (in a list). You have 24h of time - 24hours*60min = 1440 minutes. So for every minute store the beginning and end index within the sorted list. Then the query is only O(1) lookup into the index.

Comment: If N is the number of lines, I think O(N) is what we are talking about. The only question is the constant cost per line, but compared to IO, it might be negligible. Maybe, using `fmap()`  or is it `mmap()`?.. could be faster than stream IO. On windows, you have some options while opening files with `CreateFile()`, such as `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL`, which might improve performance.

Comment: @AndrejKesely could you show me what you mean in code? I see how you convert to 1440 but not the indexing part

Comment: @BitTickler how would I implement that in Java or python?

Comment: extending on @AndrejKesely idea if you need multiple queries on the **same** input, you could also do 86400 lists for each second of a day.

Comment: @Yunnosch added my extremely slow approach

Comment: @fastmath I am allergic to both Java and Python. And if you want performance (java is performant I think, but surely not python), pick a faster language. For a prototype, I recommend haskell in this case as I remember it having good IO performance for a high level language.

Comment: @fastmath Then some seconds contain empty lists?!

Comment: @AndrejKesely this wold work if daylight savings time didn't exist

Comment: 1. Please mention in your question the fact that you want to do this multiple times with different ranges; it's important information (your current approach is essentially optimal for a once-off). 2. Build an array of (time, name) pairs and sort them by time; then to answer a query, binary-search the starting and ending times.

Comment: The fastest way is probably to construct a RegEx that matches (or doesn't match) the times you are looking for. Yes, it would be a huge RegEx and hard to build, but it would be very fast!

Comment: Can the names include numbers and periods or other punctuation? https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: What about midnight? Can the time range be 23:30 to 01:15?

Comment: The fastest way is: construct a DFA and execute it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker information added. Do you have any sample code I code learn from? I've never done any kind of binary search. I also edited the time to include dates so the filter can account for daylight savings time in my timezone

Comment: @IanMercer added note stating the algorithm will run multiple times. Recreating regex cases during every run could add more computational complexity

Comment: @IanMercer no, only text is allowed in the names. The date/time portion has hyphens, a whitespace, and a colon. Added date to the last part of the strings so the data can be more descriptive (and account for time zone math, if needed, for the filter)

Comment: @IanMercer (Andrej's answer above might not work if an hour is lost or gained on a given day - all times in the data are unfortunately entered as local time)

Comment: @IanMercer Excellent questions! Time ranges must always be on the same day and the starting time is always earlier than the end time. Added this to the main question

Comment: @wildplasser Could you please provide sample code / solution using DFA? It sounds powerful and would love to learn more about it through seeing it in action

Comment: There are tons of resources on the web about binary search -- after sorting, it's probably the most well-known algorithm in the world. I'm betting Java already has an implementation of it somewhere.

Comment: This question is kind of a moving target :) And how fast do you need? My unoptimized lisp  queries time intervals really fast (5M lines, query 1 minute interval): (time (query-interval *data* 15 0 15 1))
Evaluation took:
  0.000 seconds of real time
  0.000047 seconds of total run time (0.000047 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  166,752 processor cycles
  98,304 bytes consed
With Andrej's 1minute bin lookup array.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Just read up on binary searches. Binary search would work if date was not part of the string would it? I added date just now, missed doing so in the original submission.

Comment: #moving-target :)

Comment: @BitTickler I promise not to add any more to the question, I sincerely apologize. Important information was missed in the original submission as I got new formatting for this data haha

Comment: Binary search works on any totally ordered set: plain integers, times, datetimes, etc.

Comment: @BitTickler have you got a solution? Whatever you have is fine, just curious

Comment: I thought your problem was in parsing the file. (I've never seen a dot-separated file!) But since your queries never span more than one day, you could bin your data, one day per bin, and just search sequentially within a bin. Or use a database.

Answer (score 0):

Some example in Python using index for every minute:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby

big_list = [
    "John.Howard.12:14",
    "Diane.Barry.13:50",
    "xxxDiane.Barryxxx.13:50",  # <-- added a name in the same HH:MM
    "Joseph.Ferns.08:02",
    "Joseph.Ferns.05:09",
    "Josephine.Fernie.07:20",
    "Alex.Alexander.10:10",
    "Howard.Jennings.12:17",
    "Hannah.Johnson.00:49",
]

# 1. sort the list by time HH:MM
big_list = sorted(big_list, key=lambda k: k[-5:])

# the list is now:

# ['Hannah.Johnson.00:49',
#  'Joseph.Ferns.05:09',
#  'Josephine.Fernie.07:20',
#  'Joseph.Ferns.08:02',
#  'Alex.Alexander.10:10',
#  'John.Howard.12:14',
#  'Howard.Jennings.12:17',
#  'Diane.Barry.13:50',
#  'xxxDiane.Barryxxx.13:50']

# 2. create an index (for every minute in a day)
index = {}

times = []
for i, item in enumerate(big_list):
    times.append(int(item[-5:-3]) * 60 + int(item[-2:]))

last = 0
cnt = 0
for v, g in groupby(times):
    for i in range(last, v):
        index[i] = [cnt, cnt]
    s = sum(1 for _ in g)
    index[v] = [cnt, cnt + s]
    cnt += s
    last = v + 1

for i in range(last, 60 * 24):
    index[i] = [cnt, cnt]


# 3. you can now do a fast query using the index
def find_all_strings(n, m):
    n = int(n[-5:-3]) * 60 + int(n[-2:])
    m = int(m[-5:-3]) * 60 + int(m[-2:])

    return big_list[index[n][0] : index[m][1]]


print(find_all_strings("00:10", "00:30"))  # []
print(find_all_strings("00:30", "00:50"))  # ['Hannah.Johnson.00:49']
print(find_all_strings("12:00", "13:55"))  # ['John.Howard.12:14', 'Howard.Jennings.12:17', 'Diane.Barry.13:50', 'xxxDiane.Barryxxx.13:50']
print(find_all_strings("13:00", "13:55"))  # ['Diane.Barry.13:50', 'xxxDiane.Barryxxx.13:50']
print(find_all_strings("15:00", "23:00"))  # []
```

Comment: Why do you use the -5, -3, and -2 values in the line: times.append(int(item[-5:-3]) * 60 + int(item[-2:])) ?

Comment: It looks like the item[-5:-3] represent the hour portion of the string, but how? why 5 and 3?

Comment: Counting characters from the left (index starting at 1) I see the fifth character being the leftmost character in the hours portion of the string. Is this correct? If so, why only -2

Comment: Oh, I see. You genius

Answer (score 0):

Since the data will be searched many times I first parse the strings to make it easy fo search multiple times = see `by_date`.

I use binary search to find the first string of a particular day then iterate through increasing times collecting appropriate strings in variable `filtered` of function `strings_between`.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562250/fastest-string-filtering-algorithm

Created on Tue May 18 09:20:11 2021

@author: Paddy3118
"""

strings = """\
John.Howard.12-11-2020 13:14
Diane.Barry.29-07-2020 20:50
Joseph.Ferns.08-05-2020 08:02
Joseph.Ferns.02-03-2020 05:09
Josephine.Fernie.01-01-2020 07:20
Alex.Alexander.06-06-2020 10:10
Howard.Jennings.07-07-2020 13:17
Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 00:49
Josephine.Fernie.08-08-2020 07:20
Alex.Alexander.08-08-2020 10:10
Howard.Jennings.08-08-2020 13:17
Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 09:49\
"""

## First parse the date information once for all future range calcs

def to_mins(hr_mn='00:00'):
    hr, mn = hr_mn.split(':')
    return int(hr) * 60 + int(mn)


by_date = dict()    # Keys are individual days, values are time-sorted
for s in strings.split('\n'):
    name_day, time = s.strip().split()
    name, day = name_day.rsplit('.', 1)
    minutes = to_mins(time)
    if day not in by_date:
        by_date[day] = [(minutes, s)]
    else:
        by_date[day].append((minutes, s))
for day_info in by_date.values():
    day_info.sort()


## Now rely on dict search for day then binary +linear search within day.

def _bisect_left(a, x):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.
    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    'a' is a list of tuples whose first item is assumed sorted and searched apon.
    """

    lo, hi = 0, len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        # Use __lt__ to match the logic in list.sort() and in heapq
        if a[mid][0] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo


def strings_between(day="01-01-2020", start="00:00", finish="23:59"):
    global by_date

    if day not in by_date:
        return []
    day_data = by_date[day]
    start, finish = to_mins(start), to_mins(finish)
    from_index = _bisect_left(day_data, start)

    filtered = []
    for time, s in day_data[from_index:]:
        if time <= finish:
            filtered.append(s)
        else:
            break
    return filtered


## Example data

assert by_date == {
 '12-11-2020': [(794, 'John.Howard.12-11-2020 13:14')],
 '29-07-2020': [(1250, 'Diane.Barry.29-07-2020 20:50')],
 '08-05-2020': [(482, 'Joseph.Ferns.08-05-2020 08:02')],
 '02-03-2020': [(309, 'Joseph.Ferns.02-03-2020 05:09')],
 '01-01-2020': [(440, 'Josephine.Fernie.01-01-2020 07:20')],
 '06-06-2020': [(610, 'Alex.Alexander.06-06-2020 10:10')],
 '07-07-2020': [(797, 'Howard.Jennings.07-07-2020 13:17')],
 '08-08-2020': [(49, 'Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 00:49'),
                (440, 'Josephine.Fernie.08-08-2020 07:20'),
                (589, 'Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 09:49'),
                (610, 'Alex.Alexander.08-08-2020 10:10'),
                (797, 'Howard.Jennings.08-08-2020 13:17')]}

## Example queries from command line
"""
In [7]: strings_between('08-08-2020')
Out[7]:
['Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 00:49',
 'Josephine.Fernie.08-08-2020 07:20',
 'Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 09:49',
 'Alex.Alexander.08-08-2020 10:10',
 'Howard.Jennings.08-08-2020 13:17']

In [8]: strings_between('08-08-2020', '09:30', '24:00')
Out[8]:
['Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 09:49',
 'Alex.Alexander.08-08-2020 10:10',
 'Howard.Jennings.08-08-2020 13:17']

In [9]: strings_between('08-08-2020', '09:49', '10:10')
Out[9]: ['Hannah.Johnson.08-08-2020 09:49', 'Alex.Alexander.08-08-2020 10:10']

In [10]:
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Paddy3118 already pointed out, binary search is probably the way to go.

1. (if your data is on disk): Load input data and sort by date/time.
2. With i0 being the start index of the result set and i1 being the end index of the result set (both obtained from binary search): enumerate resulting entries.

The code I used (in Lisp) is shown at the end of this answer. It is not optimized in the slightest (I guess it would be possible to make the loading and initial sorting much faster with a some optimization effort).

This is how my interactive session looked like (includes timing information, for my foo.txt input file containing 5 million entries).

> **rlwrap sbcl --dynamic-space-size 2048**
> This is SBCL 2.1.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
> More information about SBCL is available at http://www.sbcl.org/.
> SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
> It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
> BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
> distribution for more information.
> **(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)**
> To load "cl-ppcre":
> Load 1 ASDF system:
> cl-ppcre
> ; Loading "cl-ppcre"
> ..
> (:CL-PPCRE)
> **(load "fivemillion.lisp")**
> T
> **(time (defparameter *data* (load-input-for-queries "foo.txt")))**
> "sorting..."
> Evaluation took:
> 32.091 seconds of real time
> 32.090620 seconds of total run time (31.386722 user, 0.703898 system)
> [ Run times consist of 2.641 seconds GC time, and 29.450 seconds non-GC time. ]
> 100.00% CPU
> 15 lambdas converted
> 115,308,171,684 processor cycles
> 6,088,198,752 bytes consed
> *DATA*
> **(time (defparameter *output* (query-interval *data* '(2018 1 1) '(2018 1 2))))**
> Evaluation took:
> 0.000 seconds of real time
> 0.000111 seconds of total run time (0.000109 user, 0.000002 system)
> 100.00% CPU
> 395,172 processor cycles
> 65,536 bytes consed
> *OUTPUT*
> **(time (defparameter *output* (query-interval *data* '(2018 1 1) '(2018 1 2 8))))**
> Evaluation took:
> 0.000 seconds of real time
> 0.000113 seconds of total run time (0.000110 user, 0.000003 system)
> 100.00% CPU
> 399,420 processor cycles
> 65,536 bytes consed
> *OUTPUT*
> **(time (defparameter *output* (query-interval *data* '(2018 1 1) '(2019 1 1))))**
> Evaluation took:
> 0.020 seconds of real time
> 0.022469 seconds of total run time (0.022469 user, 0.000000 system)
> 110.00% CPU
> 80,800,092 processor cycles
> 15,958,016 bytes consed
> *OUTPUT*

So, while the load and sort time (done once) is nothing to write home about (but could be optimized), the `(query-interval ...)` calls are pretty fast. The bigger the result set of the query, the longer the list the function returns (more conses, more run time). I could have been more clever and just return the start and end indices of the result set and leave the collecting of the entries to the caller.

Here the source code, which also includes code for generating the test data sets I used:

```lisp
(defun random-uppercase-character ()
  (code-char (+ (char-code #\A) (random 26))))
(defun random-lowercase-character ()
  (code-char (+ (char-code #\a) (random 26))))
(defun random-name-part (nchars)
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (write-char (random-uppercase-character) stream)
    (loop repeat (- nchars 1) do
      (write-char (random-lowercase-character) stream))))
(defun random-day-of-month ()
  "Assumes every month has 31 days, because it does not matter
for this exercise."
  (+ 1 (random 31)))
(defun random-month-of-year ()
  (+ 1 (random 12)))
(defun random-year ()
  "Some year between 2017 and 2022"
  (+ 2017 (random 5)))
(defun random-hour-of-day ()
  (random 24))
(defun random-minute-of-hour ()
  (random 60))
(defun random-entry (stream)
  (format stream "\"~a.~a.~d-~d-~d ~d:~d\"~%"
      (random-name-part 10)
      (random-name-part 10)
      (random-day-of-month)
      (random-month-of-year)
      (random-year)
      (random-hour-of-day)
      (random-minute-of-hour)))
(defun generate-input (entry-count file-name)
  (with-open-file (stream
           file-name
           :direction :output
           :if-exists :supersede)
    (loop repeat entry-count do
      (random-entry stream))))

(defparameter *line-scanner*
  (ppcre:create-scanner
   "\"(\\w+).(\\w+).(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s(\\d+):(\\d+)\""))
;;      0       1      2      3      4        5      6
;;      fname   lname  day    month  year     hour   minute

(defun decompose-line (line)
  (let ((parts (nth-value
        1
        (ppcre:scan-to-strings
         *line-scanner*
         line))))
    (make-array 7 :initial-contents
        (list (aref parts 0)
              (aref parts 1)
              (parse-integer (aref parts 2))
              (parse-integer (aref parts 3))
              (parse-integer (aref parts 4))
              (parse-integer (aref parts 5))
              (parse-integer (aref parts 6))))))
(defconstant +fname-index+ 0)
(defconstant +lname-index+ 1)
(defconstant +day-index+ 2)
(defconstant +month-index+ 3)
(defconstant +year-index+ 4)
(defconstant +hour-index+ 5)
(defconstant +minute-index+ 6)
(defvar *compare-<-criteria*
  (make-array 5 :initial-contents
          (list +year-index+
            +month-index+
            +day-index+
            +hour-index+
            +minute-index+)))

(defun compare-< (dl1 dl2)
  (labels ((comp (i)
         (if (= i 5)
         nil
         (let ((index (aref *compare-<-criteria* i)))
           (let ((v1 (aref dl1 index))
             (v2 (aref dl2 index)))
             (cond
               ((< v1 v2) t)
               ((= v1 v2) (comp (+ i 1)))
               (t nil)))))))
    (comp 0)))
           
(defun time-stamp-to-index (hours minutes)
  (+ minutes (* 60 hours)))

(defun load-input-for-queries (file-name)
  (let* ((decomposed-line-list
       (with-open-file (stream file-name :direction :input)
         (loop for line = (read-line stream nil nil)
           while line
           collect (decompose-line line))))
     (number-of-lines (length decomposed-line-list))
     (decomposed-line-array (make-array number-of-lines
                        :initial-contents
                        decomposed-line-list)))
    (print "sorting...") (terpri)
    (sort decomposed-line-array #'compare-<)))

(defun unify-date-list (date)
  (let ((date-length (length date)))
    (loop
      for i below 5
      collecting (if (> date-length i) (nth i date) 0))))

(defun decomposed-line-date<date-list (decomposed-line date-list)
  (labels ((comp (i)
         (if (= i 5)
         nil
         (let ((index (aref *compare-<-criteria* i)))
           (let ((v1 (aref decomposed-line index))
             (v2 (nth i date-list)))
             (cond
               ((< v1 v2) t)
               ((= v1 v2) (comp (+ i 1)))
               (t nil)))))))
    (comp 0)))

(defun index-before (data key predicate
             &key (left 0) (right (length data)))
  (if (and (< left right) (> (- right left) 1))
      (if (funcall predicate (aref data left) key)
      (let ((mid (+ left (floor (- right left) 2))))
        (if (funcall predicate (aref data mid) key)
        (index-before data key predicate
                  :left mid
                  :right right)
        (index-before data key predicate
                  :left left
                  :right mid)))
      left)
      right))

(defun query-interval (data start-date end-date)
  "start-date and end-date are given as lists of the form:
'(year month day hour minute) or shorter versions e.g.
'(year month day hour), omitting trailing values which will be
appropriately defaulted."
  (let ((d0 (unify-date-list start-date))
    (d1 (unify-date-list end-date)))
    (let* ((start-index (index-before
             data
             d0
             #'decomposed-line-date<date-list))
       (end-index (index-before
               data
               d1
               #'decomposed-line-date<date-list
               :left (cond
                   ((< start-index 0) 0)
                   ((>= start-index (length data))
                (length data))
                   (t start-index)))))
      (loop for i from start-index below end-index
        collecting (aref data i)))))
```